How do I reconnect programs to pulseaudio after a restart?
OS is Debian 12. Every now and then, in pavucontrol I'll see: "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait..."
So it looks like pulseaudio crashed. I restarted pulseaudio with pulseaudio -k and everything looks good in pavucontrol, but all my audio programs are now missing from the playback tab. I'm guessing they "lost the connection" to pulseaudio when it crashed.
How do I restore these connections without having to restart each program? I have a few dozen audio programs that were connected to pulseaudio before the crash, and I really don't want to have to restart each one, as restoring the full state/workflow of each program would take quite a bit of time.

You might consider trying pipewire... it can subsume PA, and - in my experience - has made my Debian audio much more reliable.

I've heard nothing but good things about pipewire, and migrating to it is definitely on my list. For now though, I want to try and recover this crashed pulseaudio session, if possible.

Tried systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service?

No such issue exists with PW.

Try using pulseaudio --start instead of pulseaudio -k.

k is for killing and start is for, well, starting.
Pulseaudio might be "confused" with the k option.


The original dialog was not irrelevant, Vlastimil, as it related my history and thus qualifications in responding to the post. Also, it is rude to edit a person's answer without speaking to them first especially on the subjective nature of what you deem to be relevant.Pochopit?

Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that the idea behind this site explicitly includes the possibility of editing by other contributors, although this should always be with the intention improving clarity where required, and not defacing the post. Still, the site is explicitly not a forum, so statements that may trigger discussions should be avoided, and the answers should not be used for directly addressing other users - there are other possibilities for that if necessary.

That said, you can always flag your own post for moderator intervention or open a question on the meta site if you feel that another user has interfered with your contributon in an unwarranted way.
